# Synonymize [modulus] and [modulo]

Tags: feature-request, synonym-request

The tags [modulus](/questions/tagged/modulus) and [modulo](/questions/tagged/modulo) refer actually to the same operation, but aren't yet synonyms. Should we synonymize them?

Comment: From what to what though?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy: I think from [modulus] to [modulo] is the best idea, because there are more [modulo] then [modulus] questions.

Comment: According to [Math.SE - What is the difference between Modulus, Absolute value and Modulo?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/472856/what-is-the-difference-between-modulus-absolute-value-and-modulo) they may mean different things depending on the context.

Comment: @Stijn: Hmmm... I see. But all questions tagged [modulus] are actually about the modulo operation.

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the real tag usage my personal opinion is that there are some possible solution we could examine.

For first, it would be goof to correct all the questions mistaking the usage of the tag [modulus] with the meaning of [modulo].

Then it's possible to delete the [modulo] tag and choose another word or sentence which could be more clear for the final users. i.e. [modulo-abs-value] and [modulo-rest].
We can think about it..

It could also be really useful to handle disambiguation (as wikipedia is doing) with tags.

> Modulus is a term used for absolute value in complex analysis, and
>   also a term used for the thing-being-divided-by in remainder
>   arithmetic (actually called modular arithmetic)